# How does Microsoft Visual C++ store signed chars and how can I test individual bits in a signed char?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, visual-c++, char

OK, so say I have a signed char with value -103:

```
char s_char = -103;
```

How does the computer store this char in bits? Is the first bit 0 because the char is negative? If so, would the computer store the char as 01100101, because 1100101 (base 2) in base 10 is 103?

And a second question: how can I access or test a single bit in the signed char? Would

```
s_char & (0x80 >> pos)
```

give me the value of the bit at position pos counting from the left?

Comment: Normally, signed integers are stored using 2's complement in contemporary computers. This is necessarily required but it make a lot of things reasonably convenient. With respect to testing which bits are actually set, I'd think you best bet is to convert the signed char to an unsigned char and then test it's bits. You can also use std::bitset<8> to easily print the pattern:
  std::cout << std::bitset<8>(static_cast<unsigned char>(s_char));

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Signed values are usually stored using Two's Complement. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement

This essentially provides a signed bit which determines whether or not the number stored is negative or positive. If you're using an 8-bit int for example, the range of possible signed numbers is -128 to 127. This breaks down to a series of 8 bits, for example, where the left-most bit represents a value of -128. The bits following 'hold' half the value as the bit to left, but are positive instead. An 8-bit number in binary form would look like this:

```
0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0
-128 64   32   16   8    4    2    1
```

Since a `char` is an integer type, it would be stored in the same way as a regular int would be. A `char` with the value of -103 would break down to something like this:

```
1    0    0    1    1    0    0    1
-128 64   32   16   8    4    2    1
```

If you want to test a single bit, you could use a mask. For example, if you wanted to test if the left most bit was set, you could do something like this:

```
s_char & (0x80)
```

This return true if the left-most bit was set to 1 in s_char, regardless of the other bits. I hope that helps!

Answer (score 3):

`char` is just an integer. 8-bit integers in most cases. So `-103` is just:

```
10011001
```

To access a single bit in a `char`, you can do it the same way as any other integer:

```
char s_char = -103;

s_char & (1 << n)
```

will get you the nth bit from the bottom.

Comment: Why would -103 be 10011001? Could you please give me an explanation? Thanks.

Comment: Take a look at the link you were given in the comments: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement It explains exactly how twos-complement representation works - including how it works for negative numbers.